# Integrating CKEditor in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, ckeditor

I'm using the CKEditor, and I developed a lot of features for it other than those exists, but now I'm trying to replace it with the built-in Rich Text Editor in sharepoint 2007 but with no luck...

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor offers a standard solution for this ([CKEditor for SharePoint](http://ckeditor.com/sharepoint)), that even comes with a 30-day fully functional trial.

It's not free, but it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I understand there's a way of doing this without the full version, I just can't seem to find the place where the degault editor is being called so I can replace it.
I think it's just a matter of replacing the editor's ID with my ID. Anyone know how to do this?